# Mongod [initandlisten] dbexit: rc: 48

Tags: mongodb

When I run mongod I recieved this error. How can I solve this? Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GagF6.png)

Comment: Try to stop current active mongodb service with `service mongod stop` and run it again

Comment: Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded.

Comment: did you use `sudo`?

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: what is the version of your OS?

Comment: OS Pardus 17.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop current active mongodb service and run it again

```
$ sudo service mongod stop
$ mongod
```

You may encounter the problem of **Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded**, this error says that your mongod is not running. Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/770133/763913)

If you use Mac

```
$ sudo killall mongod
```

If it did not work, try to find out which process is running on **port** (27017) and kill it

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :27017
```

Kill the process

```
$ sudo kill <pid>
```

Or just try on another port with `mongod --port 27027`

Comment: After "sudo service mongod stop" -> "Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded."